# Use Observing to modify the option value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, magento

I am trying to use the Magento reloadPrice() with javaScript to reload the price. I have a configurable product with custom options.

```
    var subPrice = 0; //is the price inside the option
            var subPriceincludeTax = 0;
            var discountRate = discountRateUrl; //discount base on database
            var price = priceUrl;//get the product price
            var discountedPrice = price*discountRate; // price * ourdiscount
            //var discountedSubPrice = subPrice*((100-test)/100); // custom option addition price * ourdiscounted prices
            //console.log(discountRate); //display the prices as int
        //console.log(discountedSubPrice);
            //console.log(test);
            Object.values(this.customPrices).each(function(el){
                if (el.excludeTax && el.includeTax) {
                    subPrice += parseFloat(el.excludeTax*discountRate); // use the var factor && this will affect the price when changing option *important
                    subPriceincludeTax += parseFloat(el.includeTax*discountRate);

                } else {
                    subPrice += parseFloat(el.price);
                    subPriceincludeTax += parseFloat(el.price);

                }
                var finalprice = ((subPrice)+discountedPrice);//checking if getting the php
                var fomattedprice = finalprice.toFixed(2); //Convert a number into a string, keeping only two decimals
                console.log(finalprice); //tester of the final prices
                console.log(discountRate);//tester discount rate in string
                document.getElementById("finalprice").innerHTML = '$' + fomattedprice ;
```

Although, this method display the price on the product page correctly but not on the shopping cart.
Let me give out an example now, for example Price of the configurable product: $150. Add an custom option for $50 with 50% discount,
The new price $175 is displayed in the product page, But not in the cart page : the cart page displays 200 which is not correct.

I know i can use obsever but i don't have any idea to do that.